# Why does a Personal Access Token (PAT) need full access to serve the Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

When accessing Azure DevOps via REST API through PowerShell, the **Personal Access Token (PAT)** used for authentication needs **Full access**.

[image: PAT scope setting]

When the PAT is set to **Custom defined** access with every scope enabled, some requests fail:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Why is **Full access** not equal to **Custom defined** access with every scope enabled and maximal permissions? Is it not possible to limit the PAT to the scopes actually concerned by the request?

Edit: The concerned REST API request:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/{definition}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Comment: Might be helpful to provide the API request you are sending

Comment: I have the same issue. Even with all permissions enabled, I am unable to use a specific endpoint. If I select the Full Access instead, it works. 

Endpoint in my case: "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{projectguid}/_api/_identity/AddTeamAdmins?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

I do a post to add an administrator to a project team. 

Did you figure out why this was the case?

Comment: Btw, this worked with a custom defined scope until about a week ago. Now it requires full access. Any idea?

Comment: I've never figured out the reason for this odd behavior. I started to use default credentials to authenticate the REST requests whenever possible to avoid to deal with PATs.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I tested the api you listed. I try to only select **Read** access in the **Build** Scope, the PAT works fine.

[image]

[image]

Also I tried setting **Custom defined** access with every scope enabled, obviously this also works fine.

In some special apis, we can only use `Full access`, because not all scopes will be listed in `Custom defined access`. The scopes of some special case apis are not defined in `Custom defined access`. For example, the api is tracked from the browser's Network and is not documented in the official documentation . You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/757815/setting-pat-scope-to-custom-defined-causes-401-una.html).

The api you use is documented in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), you can try to test in Postman to see if the same result.

Comment: I tried again. Enable Read access in the Build scope for the PAT is not working for me and this particular request. For other requests it works. For example I can get build definitions. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: You can try to revoke the previous PAT and recreate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to download a file using curl and this needed a PAT. in GitHub it worked without a PAT.
When I set Personal Access Token to Full Access in Azure DevOps Settings it worked fine. So I set Custom then enabled all of the custom defined access scopes.

I had to click the button at the bottom:

[image: Show all scopes in PAT settings]

This listed all of the scopes when I enabled all of them authentication worked. I then disabled 5 at a time and retested and found the one I needed was Token Administration [Read & Manage] only.

[image: Token Administration Scope Image]